# prove we can find two vectors in $V_1, V_2$ with zero inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I want to prove that given $(\cdot,\cdot)$ an inner product space on $V$ above $F$ with $\mathscr{dim}=n$, if $n>2$ and $V_1,V_2$ are different linear subspaces of $V$ with $\mathscr{dim}= n-1$ then there are exist $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$, while $v_1,v_2\neq0$, such as $(v_1,v_2)=0$. Would appreciate some help how to prove it.

Comment: Indeed a stronger statement should be true: if $\dim V_1=n-1$ and $v_2$ is *any* fixed vector, then there exists $v_1\in V_1$ such that $\langle v_1,v_2\rangle = 0$. Do you know what the "orthogonal complement of $v_2$" is?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much. secondly, yes I do but how would I be sure that v2 for that matter is the orthogonal complement of 1, maybe it doesn't has one or maybe it does but not one which belongs to V2, or am I missing something?

Comment: The orthogonal complement of $v_2$ has dimension $n-1$ as well (assuming $v_2\ne0$). What about its intersection with $V_1$?